# Raw field values in content editor

Tags: content-editor

Sitecore content editor is displaying raw values of only some fields even though `Raw values` is **not** checked. This happening on only certain fields such as `Final rendering, Workflow, States and Default workflow`. Other fields seems to be displaying normal rendered value.

Functionality wise there are no broken links or rendering. I can go to the page and it renders and behave as expected.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

[image: raw values instead of rendering]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50768/discussion-on-question-by-xoail-raw-field-values-in-content-editor).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some default Sitecore templates have been changed or accidentally misconfigured.

Double check `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Layout` and `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Workflow` between a clean/working install of Sitecore and our own instance.

If the templates are different then change them to match, or if you think there may be other templates also affected then package up entire sections of the tree and override in your corrupted version. You should not lose any content that way (but always take backups first).